# url to url redirection using html

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, google-apps-script, contact-form

I'm trying to submit a contact form using google-app-script. When I'm submit that, it displays the following page:
https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbx-sxqjOmCD5pGhLzzcI9Tc906bZN5VnNQQCe34/exec

I want this url to to redirect to my another page, how can I achieve that using scripts.

Below is the script. Just for the info, I'm a beginner.

```
/******************************************************************************
 * This tutorial is based on the work of Martin Hawksey twitter.com/mhawksey  *
 * But has been simplified and cleaned up to make it more beginner friendly   *
 * All credit still goes to Martin and any issues/complaints/questions to me. *
 ******************************************************************************/

// if you want to store your email server-side (hidden), uncomment the next line
 var TO_ADDRESS = "abc@gmail.com";

// spit out all the keys/values from the form in HTML for email
// uses an array of keys if provided or the object to determine field order
function formatMailBody(obj, order) {
  var result = "";
  if (!order) {
    order = Object.keys(obj);
  }

  // loop over all keys in the ordered form data
  for (var idx in order) {
    var key = order[idx];
    result += "<h4 style='text-transform: capitalize; margin-bottom: 0'>" + key + "</h4><div>" + sanitizeInput(obj[key]) + "</div>";
    // for every key, concatenate an `<h4 />`/`<div />` pairing of the key name and its value, 
    // and append it to the `result` string created at the start.
  }
  return result; // once the looping is done, `result` will be one long string to put in the email body
}

// sanitize content from the user - trust no one 
// ref: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-output#appendUntrusted(String)
function sanitizeInput(rawInput) {
   var placeholder = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(" ");
   placeholder.appendUntrusted(rawInput);

   return placeholder.getContent();
 }

function doPost(e) {

  try {
    Logger.log(e); // the Google Script version of console.log see: Class Logger
    record_data(e);

    // shorter name for form data
    var mailData = e.parameters;

    // names and order of form elements (if set)
    var orderParameter = e.parameters.formDataNameOrder;
    var dataOrder;
    if (orderParameter) {
      dataOrder = JSON.parse(orderParameter);
    }

    // determine recepient of the email
    // if you have your email uncommented above, it uses that `TO_ADDRESS`
    // otherwise, it defaults to the email provided by the form's data attribute
    var sendEmailTo = (typeof TO_ADDRESS !== "undefined") ? TO_ADDRESS : mailData.formGoogleSendEmail;

    // send email if to address is set
    if (sendEmailTo) {
      MailApp.sendEmail({
        to: String(sendEmailTo),
        subject: "About Me: Contact form submitted",
        // replyTo: String(mailData.email), // This is optional and reliant on your form actually collecting a field named `email`
        htmlBody: formatMailBody(mailData, dataOrder)
      });
    }

    return ContentService    // return json success results
          .createTextOutput(
            JSON.stringify({"result":"success",
                            "data": JSON.stringify(e.parameters) }))
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  } catch(error) { // if error return this
    Logger.log(error);
    return ContentService
          .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"error", "error": error}))
          .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  }
}


/**
 * record_data inserts the data received from the html form submission
 * e is the data received from the POST
 */
function record_data(e) {
  var lock = LockService.getDocumentLock();
  lock.waitLock(30000); // hold off up to 30 sec to avoid concurrent writing

  try {
    Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e)); // log the POST data in case we need to debug it

    // select the 'responses' sheet by default
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheetName = e.parameters.formGoogleSheetName || "responses";
    var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(sheetName);

    var oldHeader = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
    var newHeader = oldHeader.slice();
    var fieldsFromForm = getDataColumns(e.parameters);
    var row = [new Date()]; // first element in the row should always be a timestamp

    // loop through the header columns
    for (var i = 1; i < oldHeader.length; i++) { // start at 1 to avoid Timestamp column
      var field = oldHeader[i];
      var output = getFieldFromData(field, e.parameters);
      row.push(output);

      // mark as stored by removing from form fields
      var formIndex = fieldsFromForm.indexOf(field);
      if (formIndex > -1) {
        fieldsFromForm.splice(formIndex, 1);
      }
    }

    // set any new fields in our form
    for (var i = 0; i < fieldsFromForm.length; i++) {
      var field = fieldsFromForm[i];
      var output = getFieldFromData(field, e.parameters);
      row.push(output);
      newHeader.push(field);
    }

    // more efficient to set values as [][] array than individually
    var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1; // get next row
    sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, row.length).setValues([row]);

    // update header row with any new data
    if (newHeader.length > oldHeader.length) {
      sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, newHeader.length).setValues([newHeader]);
    }
  }
  catch(error) {
    Logger.log(error);
  }
  finally {
    lock.releaseLock();
    return;
  }

}

function getDataColumns(data) {
  return Object.keys(data).filter(function(column) {
    return !(column === 'formDataNameOrder' || column === 'formGoogleSheetName' || column === 'formGoogleSendEmail' || column === 'honeypot');
  });
}

function getFieldFromData(field, data) {
  var values = data[field] || '';
  var output = values.join ? values.join(', ') : values;
  return output;
}
```

Comment: You can't unless you control `google.com` :)

Answer (score 1):

I tried to see your script, but it return this error: `Script function not found: doGet`

However, you could try do this...

```
window.location.href = "YOUR_URL";
```

Comment: Hello Felipe, I've followed https://github.com/dwyl/learn-to-send-email-via-google-script-html-no-server. Have same script. It is redirecting me to url. I want to redirect to my page. I've tried window.location.href = "YOUR_URL";, but it is automatic redirecting, not when submit is done.